# post:create in rspec test giving 'count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I've got a problem with testing a `create` method of a controller. My test:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  it "creates a new admin_user" do
    expect{
      post :create, :admin_user => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:admin_user)
    }.to change(Admin::User,:count).by(1)
  end
end
```

And the failed spec I'm getting:

```
1) Admin::UsersController logged in POST #create creates a new admin_user
     Failure/Error: expect{
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/admin_users_controller_spec.rb:75:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my controller:

```
  def create
    @admin_user = Admin::User.new(params[:admin_user])
    if @admin_user.save
      render nothing: true
    end
  end
```

and a factory:

```
require "factory_girl"
require 'ffaker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_user, class: "Admin::User" do |f|
    f.name {Faker::Name.first_name}
    f.email {Faker::Internet.email}
    f.password "aaa"
  end
end
```

and my model:

```
class Admin::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true 
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
end
```

I have no idea what might be wrong. I've searched *the whole internet* for it but didn't find the answer. Adding user from the rails console works just fine. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:admin_user)
```

Should be this:

```
post :create, :admin_user => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:admin_user)
```

As an exercise, print out the params (`p params` or `puts params.inspect`) in your create action in your controller and you'll see the difference.

**EDIT** You should try 2 things:

1. Still print out the param to see if they make sense to you.
2. The problem might be that your params just aren't valid. Instead of using `save`, try using `save!` which will throw an error if any of your validations are wrong, and you'll see the error in your test output. You should handle the situation if the save fails anyways.

Comment: That's what I had first, yet trying to change the code when looking for the fix, accidentally I've put the _changed_ code here. Already updated. Test still failing.

Comment: ad. 1 both params seem identical in structure: controller's `{:name=>"Dannie", :email=>"camden@emmerichshields.us", :password=>"aaa"}` and from a factory `{:name=>"Abbey", :email=>"herbert.schimmel@oreilly.co.uk", :password=>"aaa"}`  ad.2  both `save` and `save!` gives me the same fail error. Thanks anyway. I really appreciate it.